# How to determine the last time the audio device was playing a file?

Tags: c, ubuntu, audio, alsa, playing

I would like to use C in order to get the last time the soundboard was playing a file. Is there a way I could do that?

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Comment: I want to make an application which warns me when I spent too much time without listening to music. And I need to be able to tell when a sound is playing.

Answer (score 1):

None of the components you are using (tools, libraries, sound servers, drivers, kernel) logs the time when a sound is played.

If you are using one specific tool to play sounds, you could modify it to log the time.

Otherwise, you have to actively monitor the current status of the sound device.
(With ALSA, you could poll `/proc/asound/card*/pcm*/sub*/status`.)

Comment: Yes. This is what I want most of all. I managed to get some info from the status file. Now I only need to learn to get info from it related to whether a sound is playing or not. Once I do that, I mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible because of *ALSA(Advanced Linux Sound Architecture)* is just kernel component that provide device drivers for sound card.But i don't know if some user-space API's  and library's like (alsa-ustils) can do that!,I advice may is better to check Sound-Player applications(VLC etc..) log  ?!